# Could an opportunity exists without products? What is the use of it?

Tags: opportunity, opportunity-lineitem

I am having a confusion whether an opportunity can exists without products. If such an opportunity exists then what would be the use of it in the context of business perspective? If i recall correctly that an opportunity amount is the sum of the cost price of the opportunity line items, is that correct? Any suggestions please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Opportunities without products are a normal use case.

For example, a business that doesn't really care to forecast by product as it develops 'opportunities' - simply knowing the customer name + amount + stage + close date is sufficient.

The Opportunity.amount must be entered by the user rather than calculated as a RSF on OpportunityLineItem.

Comment: Thanks @crop1645. Can a opportunity equal to an order in salesforce. How order differs from an opportunity, though it too have order line item same like opportunity like item?

Comment: An Opportunity represents an 'opportunity' to sell something(s) on a given date. The stage tracks the lifecycle of the selling process.  An Order represents what was actually sold, typically backed up by a customer's purchase order document.  Orders will have line items and might originate from an ERP system that flows its data into SFDC Order.  Copying an order's line items into the Opportunity Product line item upon some event is a common use case.  Thus, the Oppo represents, once closed-won, the actual SKUs sold, their sales price, and the Oppo amount is the RSF of the line items.

Comment: Excellent explanation. Thanks a lot @crop1647.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, an opportunity can exist without products but the Amount would need to either be manually populated or populated via a workflow rule/trigger(only auto updates when products do exist). We do not use the standard products and use a workflow rule to update the Amount field based on a rollup of a custom object.